# How to replace Component Did update with use Effect and set state in it in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my code I am trying to replace the code from class based component to state based component.

Which I almost did but here as suggested used use Effect to replace the componentDidUpdate which later in it I set the state after receiving the updated props which I set in state and then updating the component. As I refresh the window it start giving me the infinity loop?

**If i set the value props or state in dependency array it start giving a infinity loop** while

removing array gives me  this error : -

****Line 69:8:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'markState', 'props.editMarkMode', 'props.studentMarkObject', and 'props.studentName'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'setMarkState(m => ...)' if you only need
'markState' in the 'setMarkState' call  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps****

Here is my `useEffect` Code.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (markState.editMarkMode !== props.editMarkMode) {
    if (props.studentMarkObject !== null) {
      const updatedStateEditCondition = { ...markState };
      updatedStateEditCondition.isValid = true;
      updatedStateEditCondition.editMarkMode = true;
      updatedStateEditCondition.studentName = props.studentName;
      updatedStateEditCondition.semester.value =
        props.studentMarkObject.semester;
      updatedStateEditCondition.semester.touched = true;
      updatedStateEditCondition.semester.valid = true;
      setMarkState(updatedStateEditCondition);
      let array = [];
      let editMarks = props.studentMarkObject.marks;
      for (let index in editMarks) {
        let object = {};
        object.subject = {};
        object.subject.value = editMarks[index].subject;
        object.subject.touched = true;
        object.subject.valid = true;
        object.markObtained = {};
        object.markObtained.value = editMarks[index].markObtained;
        object.markObtained.touched = true;
        object.markObtained.valid = true;
        array.push(object);
      }
      setMarkState({ ...markState, marks: array });
    }
  }
}, []);
```

And My `state`

```
const [markState, setMarkState] = useState({
  semester: {
    value: "",
    touched: false,
    valid: false,
  },
  marks: [
    {
      subject: {
        value: "",
        touched: false,
        valid: false,
      },
      markObtained: {
        value: "",
        touched: false,
        valid: false,
      },
    },
  ],
  isValid: false,
  editMarkMode: false,
  studentName: "",
  addBtnDisable: false,
  subBtnDisable: true,
});
```

Comment: add the `markState` to your dependency array. the [] at useEffect/ something like [markState]

Comment: I tried and i did but that lead to an infinity loop as mark State update and receive a new mark State value every time.

Comment: Why don't you stripe that state into smaller ones?

Comment: I am pretty sure the problem is the array of dependencies in your `useEffect`. As I can see you depend on: `markState`, `props.editMarkMode` and `props.studentMarkObject.marks`

Comment: As I am keeping markState , props.editMarkMode & props.studentMarkObject.marks dependencies to my array it goes to infinity loop.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding dependencies and updating the state once?

```
useEffect(() => {


if (markState.editMarkMode !== props.editMarkMode) {
    if (props.studentMarkObject !== null) {
      const updatedStateEditCondition = { ...markState };
      updatedStateEditCondition.isValid = true;
      updatedStateEditCondition.editMarkMode = true;
      updatedStateEditCondition.studentName = props.studentName;
      updatedStateEditCondition.semester.value =
        props.studentMarkObject.semester;
      updatedStateEditCondition.semester.touched = true;
      updatedStateEditCondition.semester.valid = true;

      let array = [];
      let editMarks = props.studentMarkObject.marks;
      for (let index in editMarks) {
        let object = {};
        object.subject = {};
        object.subject.value = editMarks[index].subject;
        object.subject.touched = true;
        object.subject.valid = true;
        object.markObtained = {};
        object.markObtained.value = editMarks[index].markObtained;
        object.markObtained.touched = true;
        object.markObtained.valid = true;
        array.push(object);
      }
      setMarkState({ ...updatedStateEditCondition, marks: array });
    }
  }
}, [markState, props.editMarkMode, props.studentMarkObject.marks]);
```